# Spring data mongodb search for ISO date

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to search for date of birth using query

```
criteria = Criteria.where("dob").lte(new DateTime().toDate());
```

And spring data mongodb generate below query:

> MongoTemplate: find using query:
>
> ```
> { "dob" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-05-16T07:55:23.257Z"}}}
> ```
>
> fields: null for class: class com.temp.model.User in collection: user

But I did not get any result.

My dob field in mongodb:

```
{"dob" : ISODate("1991-01-23T00:00:00Z")}
```

**How I can search for *dob* in ISODate format ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code should work fine for what you need:

```
criteria = Criteria.where("dob").lte(new java.util.Date());
```

My test is with following code, which does work fine:

```
Lis<User> users = mongoOps.find(query(where("isActive").is(true).and("CreatedDate").lte(new java.util.Date())), User.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

Query would execute perfect from Spring data mongodb0

> { "dob" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-05-16T07:55:23.257Z"}}}.

But It will not execute from mongo CLI.

Query to execute on cli.

> {dob:ISODate("2015-05-15T07:55:23.257Z")}

Thanks

Comment: Work perfectly from Spring mongo Query annotation.

Comment: What if we are using JPA MongoRepository? how can we call the $date or isodate without getting a parse exception in @Query annotation?

Comment: If there is an index on dob will that be picked since it is translated to $date?

Answer (score 4):

For IDE use ISODate() for SPRING DAO convert string to Date object

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("created").ne(null).andOperator(
                Criteria.where("created").gte(DateUtils.getDate("2016-04-14 00:00:00", DateUtils.DB_FORMAT_DATETIME)),
                Criteria.where("created").lte(DateUtils.getDate("2016-04-14 23:59:59", DateUtils.DB_FORMAT_DATETIME))
            ));


public final class DateUtils {    

    public static final String DB_FORMAT_DATETIME = "yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss";        

    private DateUtils() {
        // not publicly instantiable
    }       

    public static Date getDate(String dateStr, String format) {
        final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            return formatter.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {                
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with T and Z in the date format :(

Answer (score 0):

```
val query = Query()
query.addCriteria( 
Criteria("info.dob").gte(dob.atStartOfDay())
```