# Best Practise for Handling Date in Spring Data MongoDb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am running into few issues around handling dates in my project. This is what I have.

- In My Entities, I am using ZonedDateTime.

private ZonedDateTime assignedOn;

- Have Configured converters in Spring to handle this

  public static class ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter {
      public static final ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter INSTANCE = new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter();
      private ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter() {}

  ```
      @Override
      public Date convert(ZonedDateTime source) {
          return source == null ? null : Date.from(source.toInstant());
      }
  }

  public static class DateToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {
      public static final DateToZonedDateTimeConverter INSTANCE = new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter();
      private DateToZonedDateTimeConverter() {}

      @Override
      public ZonedDateTime convert(Date source) {
          return source == null ? null : ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
      }
  }
  ```
- I see that data is stored in Mongodb as ISO date. This what i see in Mongodb.

"completed_on" : ISODate("2017-04-12T20:02:40.000+0000"),

My Question is related to querying these date fields using Spring.  If I want to find all the records (equals operator) matching only the date part and not the time part, what should be the approach? I saw example in this thread

[Spring data mongodb search for ISO date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273355/spring-data-mongodb-search-for-iso-date)

Which suggest something like this.

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("created").ne(null).andOperator(
                Criteria.where("created").gte(DateUtils.getDate("2016-04-14 00:00:00", DateUtils.DB_FORMAT_DATETIME)),
                Criteria.where("created").lte(DateUtils.getDate("2016-04-14 23:59:59", DateUtils.DB_FORMAT_DATETIME))
            ));
```

Just wanted to see if this is the only approach or there's another elegant way to do this?